# Use output sound from one application as input sound to another (Mac OSX 10.6)

Tags: macos, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recording speaker output on MacBook with OS X Snow Leopard](https://superuser.com/questions/122539/recording-speaker-output-on-macbook-with-os-x-snow-leopard)

Is there any way to make the output sound from one application the input sound to another?

Basically, I want to redirect the output sound from `say` or Firefox to Skype, so Skype uses this instead of line in or microphone, while still having the sound from Skype going to the speakers or line out.

(You guessed right by the way - this is for prank calling friends with the Zarvox voice and/or the [Schwarzenegger Soundboard](http://www.ebaumsworld.com/soundboards/play/1879/), but there might also be useful applications :)

I am looking for either a script solution or an open source program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use for [soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/). Sadly it is not open source or a script, but it is free. The open source alternative is jack, but neither skype or firefox will use jack directly, and jack is designed more for high performance low latency routing than for ease of desktop usage.

Comment: It works like a charm :-) And it's free as in beer + GNU GPLv2 so it could be much worse.

Comment: oh wow, I had no idea it was gpl, cool

Comment: Apparently it is open source (at least now?) https://github.com/RogueAmoeba/Soundflower