# Recording speaker output on MacBook with OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, audio-recording

Does anyone know a way of recording speaker output on a MacBook with OS X Snow Leopard? I have written a program that generates music, and just want to record its output.

I do not have a feedback cable or a microphone.

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/58188/is-there-a-way-to-listen-to-the-input-sound-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/) and make the output and input Soundflower via the "Sounds" preference pane in System Preferences.

Comment: This answer is now almost 5 years old and the newest post at the given link is from 2006. Is Soundflower still the best option available for this?

Answer (score 5):

I would use [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) with [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

> **Soundflower** is a Mac OS X (10.2 and later) system extension that
>   allows applications to pass audio to other applications. Soundflower
>   is easy to use, it simply presents itself as an audio device, allowing
>   any audio application to send and receive audio with no other support
>   needed. Soundflower is free, open-source, and runs on Mac Intel and
>   PPC computers.

[image]

> **Audacity** is free, open source software for recording and editing
>   sounds. It is available for Mac OS X, Microsoft Windows, GNU/Linux,
>   and other operating systems.

[image]

Comment: http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_mac.html

Answer (score 2):

**[Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/)**.

> Record any audio - three simple words to explain Audio Hijack Pro.
>   Record from applications like iTunes, Skype or DVD Player. Record from
>   microphones, Radiosharks and other hardware. If you hear it, you can
>   record it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**[WireTap Studio](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/wiretap/)**.

> Using WireTap Studio, you can record the discrete audio output of any
>   application, as well as all system audio, or record audio input from
>   any microphone, line-in, or audio input hardware.
>
> If you can hear it, WireTap Studio can record it.
>
> Once you have recorded your audio, you can easily organize your
>   recordings in the convenient Recording Library, and edit them with
>   WireTap Studio's integrated lossless audio editor.

[image]